# R create reference manual with R CMD rd2pdf

Tags: r, manual, r-package

I am creating a R package and want to make a pdf manual with it. I was using `rd2pdf` command for this. I have written 
`R CMD Rd2pdf "C:/Users/razrahma/Documents/RPackage/mypackage"` in the console. But it is showing `Error: unexpected symbol in "R CMD"`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you typing this into the R console? I may be wrong but I think you need to execute this from the command line or a batch file.

Comment: I found it. system("R CMD Rd2pdf MyRpackage"), if I type this in command line, it will automatically creates the pdf manual.